# Scaling the active model in Blender with Python

Tags: python, scripting, blender

So I want to write a python script in Blender to automate the scaling of a model. The command for scaling is `bpy.data.objects["ObjectName"].scale()`. I however want to be able to do this independent of the object name with the same script, by just selecting the mesh I want scaled. Is this possible? What do I write in place of ObjectName to make it more versatile?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`bpy.context`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bpy.context.html) contains a lot of items related to current state within blender.

There are two properties you may want to use, `bpy.context.active_object` and `bpy.context.selected_objects`, the second is a list of the selected objects you can loop over so you can work on more than one object at a time.

You will find [blender.stackexchange.com](http://blender.stackexchange.com) is a better place to ask blender specific python and user questions.